# Word for "related to personal life"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In some situations things relate to personal life in a weird way, like for example a school lesson on the phases of grief while you happen to be in said phases of grief (not that this is the situation for me)

I cannot think of any better word than "irony" but it seems really off

*Is there a better word or phrase that carries this meaning?*

Edit:

So let me briefly describe the situation

In a roleplay the GM is describing how my character feels uneasy/anxious and is shaking for unknown reason, which is quite ___(ironic?) because indeed, I in real life am shaking and feeling anxious for unknown reason. I herewith hope to clarify what I am looking for

Comment: What about [sympathy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sympathy?s=t)?

Comment: This is a ***coincidence***. But I suspect that the simple word "coincidence" is not what you are looking for. Is it something you are glad about, or something that makes the situation a whole lot worse. In other words it could be a "happy coincidence", and "ironic coincidence", simply a "coincidence", or perhaps a "bitter coincidence".

Comment: By the way, remember "I before e, except after c" - ***grief***. .

Comment: @WS2 that actually comes quite close, I would describe the actual use I would have for this word but it would feel too much like writing in self-pity

Comment: Could it be a ***pitiful coincidence***?

Comment: @WS2 well, it is a pitiful coincidence, but that phrase doesn't quite fit in the way I would like to use it... I think I would be better off briefly explaining the situation i want to use the word in

Comment: @WS2 i edited to clarify how i would like to use the word/phrase I am looking for

Comment: @7H3_H4CK3R I think *ironic coincidence* is what you want. Unless it really is *pitiful*, or something else. Only you know how to express how you feel.

Comment: @WS2 as suggested by Phillip Siebold, "too close to home" fits very well, so far it is the best suggestion and I prefer it over the ways of using the word "coincidence"

Comment: Yes, that's a good metaphor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**too close to home** - a phrase and not a word that can have many uses but I think fits here.  In the context below, it is to be interpreted as being something resembling what the narrator was doing.

*My character was shaking inexplicably, which was a bit **too close to home** as I too was shaking.*

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly as I can also use this phrase when speaking directly to the GM